# How to subset rows with only odd numbers in 1 column in R

Tags: r, subset

I want to compile only rows containing odd numbers in one of the columns. An example of my data frame is below:

```
V1       V2     V3       V4        V5     V6      V7       V8
14221    USDJPY 20030507 20:00:00  116.33 116.19  116.47   116.25
14222    USDJPY 20030507 21:00:00  116.24 116.24  116.42   116.32
14223    USDJPY 20030507 22:00:00  116.33 116.29  116.42   116.40
14224    USDJPY 20030507 23:00:00  116.42 116.34  116.44   116.42
14227    USDJPY 20030508 02:00:00  116.48 116.42  116.67   116.58
14228    USDJPY 20030508 03:00:00  116.57 116.50  116.65   116.62
14229    USDJPY 20030508 04:00:00  116.61 116.59  116.67   116.62
14230    USDJPY 20030508 05:00:00  116.63 116.62  116.72   116.63
14231    USDJPY 20030508 06:00:00  116.64 116.56  116.64   116.62
14232    USDJPY 20030508 07:00:00  116.62 116.57  116.67   116.58
14264    USDJPY 20030509 15:00:00  117.40 117.29  117.44   117.29
14265    USDJPY 20030509 16:00:00  117.30 117.19  117.34   117.20
14266    USDJPY 20030509 17:00:00  117.19 117.19  117.26   117.19
14267    USDJPY 20030509 18:00:00  117.18 117.17  117.26   117.20
14268    USDJPY 20030509 19:00:00  117.22 117.17  117.25   117.19
14269    USDJPY 20030509 20:00:00  117.18 117.17  117.24   117.22
14270    USDJPY 20030509 21:00:00  117.23 117.18  117.25   117.18
14271    USDJPY 20030512 00:00:00  117.25 117.08  117.25   117.09
14272    USDJPY 20030512 01:00:00  117.10 116.59  117.10   116.99
14273    USDJPY 20030512 02:00:00  116.98 116.89  117.01   116.93
14274    USDJPY 20030512 03:00:00  116.94 116.84  116.94   116.88
```

I would like to take a subset of data which contain rows that has odd numbers in column V3 such that my new data frame will be as below:

```
V1       V2     V3       V4        V5     V6      V7       V8
14221    USDJPY 20030507 20:00:00  116.33 116.19  116.47   116.25
14222    USDJPY 20030507 21:00:00  116.24 116.24  116.42   116.32
14223    USDJPY 20030507 22:00:00  116.33 116.29  116.42   116.40
14224    USDJPY 20030507 23:00:00  116.42 116.34  116.44   116.42
14264    USDJPY 20030509 15:00:00  117.40 117.29  117.44   117.29
14265    USDJPY 20030509 16:00:00  117.30 117.19  117.34   117.20
14266    USDJPY 20030509 17:00:00  117.19 117.19  117.26   117.19
14267    USDJPY 20030509 18:00:00  117.18 117.17  117.26   117.20
14268    USDJPY 20030509 19:00:00  117.22 117.17  117.25   117.19
14269    USDJPY 20030509 20:00:00  117.18 117.17  117.24   117.22
14270    USDJPY 20030509 21:00:00  117.23 117.18  117.25   117.18
```

Comment: You question is very broad, and at least for me, not clear. Please explain well and if possibile post a little piece of reproducible code.

Comment: Sorry for being to brief. I have fixed my question. I hope it's fine now and will not cause further anger and resentment. My apologies!

Comment: apology taken, thanks for clarifying! deleted my comment

Comment: Still zero effort. Google "r odd numbers" please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is quite badly formulated but if I understand it correctly it would mean doing something like that:

```
col=3 #col is the # of the column where the numbers should be odd
dat[dat[,col]%%2==1,] #dat is the data frame or matrix containing your data
```

Or in the example you give you can also do

```
dat<-read.table("clipboard",header=T) #after having CTR+C the example frame from the question
dat[dat$V3 %% 2 == 1,]
```

Comment: Sorry Sir/Madam! I have added more details in my question. I didn't realise it was that vague.

Comment: Looks much better now. Thanks for clarifying. Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Thanks @Prolix, but it's not working. It returns an empty data frame.

Comment: Is your original data really like your example? Because when I load your data frame from the clipboard it works fine.

Comment: Yes it is. It is exactly taken from my actual data. Let me try it again with the fraction of data I copied here as well.

Comment: You are right! It does work on the example data set. But still doesn't work on the actual data, which has 86030 rows. I'll get to the bottom of this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: 86030 rows is not very big. This should not be an issue for R. But without having the data or an error message there is not much I can do to help further. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter(V3 %% 2 == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a particular column

```
df[df$V3 %% 2 != 0, ]
```

if your data.frame is `df`

Assuming you want to subset rows with an odd number in any column

If your data is

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
b <- c(1,2,3,5,6,6)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

> df
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 5
5 5 6
6 6 6
```

try

```
df <- df[rowSums(df %% 2)!=0, ]

> df
  a b
1 1 1
3 3 3
4 4 5
5 5 6
```

Comment: Hi. To clarify, I'm trying to subset rows containing only odd numbers in 1 of the columns.

Comment: I edited my answer. In your inital version, I thought you wanted to check all columns for odd values.

Comment: Sorry about that. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

For ease, create a function that tests for odd numbers. It's a two-liner, but everything great doesn't happen in one line. I +1 SabDem's dplyr answer. I like that one.

```
is.odd <- function(v) v %% 2 != 0
```

And you can use that function for any other instance having to do with odd numbers.

```
df1[is.odd(df1$V3), ]
      V1     V2       V3       V4     V5     V6     V7
1  14221 USDJPY 20030507 20:00:00 116.33 116.19 116.47
2  14222 USDJPY 20030507 21:00:00 116.24 116.24 116.42
3  14223 USDJPY 20030507 22:00:00 116.33 116.29 116.42
4  14224 USDJPY 20030507 23:00:00 116.42 116.34 116.44
11 14264 USDJPY 20030509 15:00:00 117.40 117.29 117.44
12 14265 USDJPY 20030509 16:00:00 117.30 117.19 117.34
       V8
1  116.25
2  116.32
3  116.40
4  116.42
11 117.29
12 117.20
```